# For a KivyMD MDBottomNavigationItem, is it even possible to change the text so that it is not all caps?

Tags: python, kivymd

I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar wherein the text of the navigation items is not in all caps.

The MDBottomNavigation default font or text style curiously seems to be all caps. For example, the Home button text in the bottom navigation bar appears: HOME. Instead, I want it to appear: Home.

Below is what I've done in Python and Kivy/KivyMD.

Python:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

root_kv = "navigation.kv"


# Initialize Application
class TennisApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.root = Builder.load_file(root_kv)


# Deploy Application
TennisApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "Navbar"
        md_bg_color: .2,.2,.2,1
        specific_text_color: .7,.7,.7,1

    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: 0,0,0,1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen1"
            text: "Home"
            icon: "home"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "MDBottomNavigation" class, once you have it, you can access the first "MDBottomNavigationItem" widget tree by using:

"B=self.M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBDeS.png).children[0].children[0]" assuming "self.M" equals to "MDBottomNavigation"

Later you can change the "font_style" of the "MDLabel" under the "BottomItem" and have it lowercase or any other font style:

"B.font_style='Caption'"

and you will be able to change it
[image]

Edit:

To change the text style, the function "change800" does it here:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
root_kv = "navigation.kv"
c="""
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Navbar"
        md_bg_color: .2,.2,.2,1
        specific_text_color: .7,.7,.7,1
    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: bar100
        panel_color: 0,0,0,1
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: item400
            name: "screen1"
            text: "Home"
            icon: "home"
"""
from kivy.clock import Clock
class TennisAppjbsidis(MDApp):
    def change800(self):
        M=self.root.ids.bar100
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]
        TEXT.font_style="Caption"
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(c) #load_file(root_kv)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:self.change800(),2)
TennisAppjbsidis().run()
```

Picture:

[image]

New Edit:
About having the same font_style for all 4 bottom items:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
root_kv = "navigation.kv"
c="""
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Navbar"
        md_bg_color: .2,.2,.2,1
        specific_text_color: .7,.7,.7,1
    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: bar100
        panel_color: 0,0,0,1
        
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: item400
            name: "screen1"
            text: "Home"
            icon: "home"
            
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: item500
            name: "screen2"
            text: "Edit"
            icon: "pencil"
            
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: item600
            name: "screen3"
            text: "Add"
            icon: "plus"
            
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: item700
            name: "screen4"
            text: "Notify"
            icon: "bell"
            
"""
from kivy.clock import Clock
class TennisAppjbsidis(MDApp):
    def change800(self):
        w="""
The following variable M is the widget:
############################
    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: bar100
        panel_color: 0,0,0,1
############################

        That's why is:
        M=self.root.ids.bar100

        So if we use:

        print(M.children)

        That equals to all the 4 MDBottomNavigationItem items of MDBottomNavigation:

        print(M.children):
        === [
        <kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationBar object at 0x7f15f11e0350>,
        <kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager object at 0x7f15f11e00b0>
        ]

        so that's just like we have a list like:

        === [A, B]
        where A is MDBottomNavigationBar widget in the widget tree,
        Remember:
        The original structure of the internal class MDBottomNavigationBar is:
###########################        
<MDBottomNavigation>
    id: panel
    orientation: 'vertical'
    height: dp(56)  # Spec

    ScreenManager:
        id: tab_manager
        transition: sm.FadeTransition(duration=.2)
        current: root.current
        screens: root.tabs

    MDBottomNavigationBar: #=== HERE IS THAT WIDGET TREE LOCATED, SO UNDER HIM, THERE ARE BOTTOM ITEMS
        id: bottom_panel
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(56)
        md_bg_color: root.theme_cls.bg_dark if not root.panel_color else root.panel_color

        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_bar
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            height: dp(56)
            size_hint: None, None
###############################
        So having:
        TEXT=M.children[0]
        print(TEXT)
        is equal to:
        ===<kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationBar object at 0x7f3618dbc350>

        That means is equal to:
        ###############################
        MDBottomNavigationBar: #=== HERE IS THAT WIDGET TREE LOCATED, SO UNDER HIM, THERE ARE BOTTOM ITEMS
            id: bottom_panel
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(56)
            md_bg_color: root.theme_cls.bg_dark if not root.panel_color else root.panel_color

            BoxLayout:
                id: tab_bar
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                height: dp(56)
                size_hint: None, None
                #here the bottom items are added because:

                ------------------------------------
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    id: item400
                    name: "screen1"
                    text: "Home"
                    icon: "home"
                    
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    id: item500
                    name: "screen2"
                    text: "Edit"
                    icon: "pencil"
                    
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    id: item600
                    name: "screen3"
                    text: "Add"
                    icon: "plus"
                    
                MDBottomNavigationItem:
                    id: item700
                    name: "screen4"
                    text: "Notify"
                    icon: "bell"

                ------------------------------------

        So now, if we use:
        
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0]
        print(TEXT)
        is equal to:
                ==== <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x7fe7e8096740>

        That "BoxLayout" widget is the same like:

        ------------------------
        MDBottomNavigationBar: #=== HERE IS THAT WIDGET TREE LOCATED, SO UNDER HIM, THERE ARE BOTTOM ITEMS
            id: bottom_panel
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(56)
            md_bg_color: root.theme_cls.bg_dark if not root.panel_color else root.panel_color

            BoxLayout: #=== THIS IS --- TEXT=M.children[0].children[0]  ---
                id: tab_bar
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                height: dp(56)
                size_hint: None, None
                #here the bottom items are added because:
        -----------------------------


        So now, if we use:
        
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0]
        print(TEXT)
        is equal to:
                ==== <kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationHeader object at 0x7fb801b59350>

        That "MDBottomNavigationHeader" widget is the same like:
        
        ----------------------------------
        <MDBottomNavigationHeader>
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.panel_color
                    #rgba: self.panel.theme_cls.bg_dark if not root.panel_color else root.panel_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            width:
                root.panel.width / len(root.panel.ids.tab_manager.screens)\
                if len(root.panel.ids.tab_manager.screens) != 0 else root.panel.width
            padding: (dp(12), dp(12))
            on_press:
                self.tab.dispatch('on_tab_press')
            on_release: self.tab.dispatch('on_tab_release')
            on_touch_down: self.tab.dispatch('on_tab_touch_down',*args)
            on_touch_move: self.tab.dispatch('on_tab_touch_move',*args)
            on_touch_up: self.tab.dispatch('on_tab_touch_up',*args)

            FloatLayout:
                id: item_container

                MDIcon:
                    id: _label_icon
                    icon: root.tab.icon
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text_size: (None, root.height)
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    text_color: root._current_color
                    valign: 'middle'
                    halign: 'center'
                    opposite_colors: root.opposite_colors
                    pos: [self.pos[0], self.pos[1]]
                    font_size: dp(24)
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}

                MDLabel:
                    id: _label
                    text: root.tab.text
                    font_style: 'Button'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text_size: (None, root.height)
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    text_color: root._current_color
                    valign: 'bottom'
                    halign: 'center'
                    opposite_colors: root.opposite_colors
                    font_size: root._label_font_size
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
        ---------------------------------

        So as you can see, there are 2 more widgets under the widget tree "MDBottomNavigationHeader"
        They are:
                ------------------------------------------------------
                MDIcon: #the icon of the Bottom item
                    id: _label_icon
                    icon: root.tab.icon
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text_size: (None, root.height)
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    text_color: root._current_color
                    valign: 'middle'
                    halign: 'center'
                    opposite_colors: root.opposite_colors
                    pos: [self.pos[0], self.pos[1]]
                    font_size: dp(24)
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}

                MDLabel: #the text of the Bottom item
                    id: _label
                    text: root.tab.text
                    font_style: 'Button'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text_size: (None, root.height)
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    text_color: root._current_color
                    valign: 'bottom'
                    halign: 'center'
                    opposite_colors: root.opposite_colors
                    font_size: root._label_font_size
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
                ----------------------------------------
        -----------------------------


        So now, if we use:
        
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]
        print(TEXT)
        is equal to:
                ==== <kivy.uix.floatlayout.FloatLayout object at 0x7fbf047775f0>

        That "FloatLayout" widget is the same like:

        -----------------------------
            FloatLayout:
                id: item_container
        -----------------------------
        in the original class "MDBottomNavigationHeader",
        
        -----------------------------


        So now, if we use:
        
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]
        print(TEXT)
        is equal to:
                ==== <kivymd.uix.label.MDLabel object at 0x7f52867f5900>

        That "MDLabel" widget is the TEXT under the bottom item icon, that's
        why you can change the "font_style"
        using:

        TEXT.font_style="Caption"

        That comes from:

        ---------------------------------
                MDLabel: #the text of the Bottom item
                    id: _label
                    text: root.tab.text
                    font_style: 'Button' #======= HERE is the TEXT.font_style="Caption"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    text_size: (None, root.height)
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                    text_color: root._current_color
                    valign: 'bottom'
                    halign: 'center'
                    opposite_colors: root.opposite_colors
                    font_size: root._label_font_size
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
        --------------------------------

        
        ###############################


        
        
"""
        M=self.root.ids.bar100
        print(M.children[0].children[0].children[2].children[0].children[0])
##################################################################
        BELL_BOTTOM_ITEM="""
        ##        MDBottomNavigationItem:
        ##            id: item700
        ##            name: "screen4"
        ##            text: "Notify"
        ##            icon: "bell"
        """
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]
        TEXT.font_style="Caption"
##################################################################
##################################################################
        PLUS_BOTTOM_ITEM="""
        ##        MDBottomNavigationItem:
        ##            id: item600
        ##            name: "screen3"
        ##            text: "Add"
        ##            icon: "plus"
        """
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[0]
        TEXT.font_style="Caption"
##################################################################
##################################################################
        PENCIL_BOTTOM_ITEM="""                  
        ##            MDBottomNavigationItem:
        ##                id: item500
        ##                name: "screen2"
        ##                text: "Edit"
        ##                icon: "pencil"
        """
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[2].children[0].children[0]
        TEXT.font_style="Caption"
##################################################################
##################################################################
        HOME_BOTTOM_ITEM="""
        ##        MDBottomNavigationItem:
        ##            id: item400
        ##            name: "screen1"
        ##            text: "Home"
        ##            icon: "home"
        """
        TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[3].children[0].children[0]
        TEXT.font_style="Caption"
##################################################################

        
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(c) #load_file(root_kv)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:self.change800(),2)
TennisAppjbsidis().run()
```

New pictures from new edit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your example "self.root" equals to "self.M" in mine

Comment: Thanks Josue. I'm new, so I'm having trouble understanding your guidance. Can you please show me your python code full screen? (In your image, your python file is being blocked by the Kivy file).

Comment: Yes I will post the complete code for you, just a moment I will edit my answer, we are here to help

Comment: Josue, this solution works if I have just one MDBottomNavigationItem---but it is not working for all four that I have. What change do I need to make to the code line below to get it to work for many children of the class MDBottomNavigation? I understand the concept of inheritance, but I don't understand why we need to repeat "children" so many times---especially when the line below is only working with one MDBottomNavigationItem (and not even the first one; it only works w/ the last item in the list.) TEXT=M.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]

Comment: Right, the attribute "children" it's needed because the native class MDBottomNavigationItem by default has some widgets under its widget tree (the source of the class) and by default, all children widgets that build that class they don't have "id" or ObjectProperty for all of the MDBottomNavigation class, that's why children attribute is needed, to apply the same to all bottom items, you can inspect the widget tree using the children attribute until you get the MDLabel widget under every bottom item widget tree (just apply the subscritable option depending on the children widget children[n])

Comment: Why does the following not work for my 4 Bottom Bar Items? I guess I don't understand to which widgets the attribute Children refers to, and I don't understand why you repeated it 5 times above:                                  
 def change_case(self):
        m = self.root.ids.bottom_bar
        text = m.children[0].children[1].children[2].children[3]
        text.font_style = "Caption"

Comment: Alright, I have added more details and added a full explanation of how the widget tree is under the bottom bar class, please check the last edit in my answer

Comment: Thanks Josué! That worked.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, here was the final elegant code that worked this out for me:      # Convert text of bottom navigation bar menu titles to lower case
    def change_case(self):
        bar = self.root.ids.bottom_bar
        for i in range(0, 5):
            text = bar.children[0].children[0].children[i].children[0].children[0]
            text.font_style = "Caption"

Answer (score 0):

add id to your MDBottomNavigation

```html
MDBottomNavigation:
    id: manager
    panel_color: 0,0,0,1
```

add this line to your build function so that each time your App builds the font_style will be override to 'Caption'

```html
def build(self):
    .......
    self.root = Builder.load_file(root_kv)    
    M = self.root.ids.manager.ids.tab_bar.children
    for tab in M:
       tab.ids._label.font_style = 'Caption'
```